# Using state setter function in child component

Tags: reactjs

I am refactoring some code and so creating a child component of some JSX. This child code uses state, but the state and its setter function is declared in the parent (App()).

For example, I have this setter function in App():

`const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = React.useState(0);`

In order to use the setter function `setSelectedIndex` in the child component, do I pass it down as props as follows?

```
<MoveList
  setSelectedIndex={setSelectedIndex}
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do that but good practice is to create a handler for that.

For example:

```
selectedIndexHandler = (index) => {
  setSelectedIndex(index)
}

<MoveList
  selectedIndexHandler={selectedIndexHandler}
/>
```

Comment: May I ask what you mean by "handler" and why that is good practice? I keep hearing the term handler everywhere.